# Normalized ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have lim of x and y axis:

```
ax.set_xlim(-1.5e-14,0e-14)
ax.set_ylim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)
```

I would like to print 6 ticks on each axis. How to do that?

```
stepx=(-1.5e-14+0e-14)/5
stepy=(-7.3e-15+7.3e-15)/5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would to use `numpy` and `matplotlib`'s `set_xticks`.

```py
import numpy as np # add this at the top

# add the two following lines after setting the limits
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(-1.5e-14, 0, 6))
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-7.3e-15, 7.3e-15, 6))
```

Comment: Thank you very much